# Reset the value of a drop down list when it is hidden again

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

Once the user selects their desired "area", they are presented with options for that specific area. I have a different hidden drop down for each area that can be selected. If the user decides to go back and select a different "area" once a selection has been made, the "area_options" becomes hidden again. When hiding "area_options", is it possible to restore the selected value back to it's original value?

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
 var area = document.getElementById('area');
 var area_options = document.getElementById('area_options');


 if(area.value === 'selection') {
                    area_options.style.display = 'block';

                } else if(area.value != 'selection') {
                    area_options.style.display = 'none';

                } else {
           }
</script>

<html>  
<tr>    
<td align='center'>
<select class='dropdown1' name='area' id='area' style='display: none;'>     
<option selected disabled>Problem Area</option>

<?php   
foreach($array_area as $value){
echo "<option value='$value'>$value</option>"; } 
?>

</td>   
</tr>   
</select>

<tr>
<td align='center'>
<div id='area_options' style='display: none;'>
<select class='dropdown1' name='area_options'>
<option selected disabled>Area Options</option>

<?php 
foreach($array_areaoptions as $value){
echo "<option value='$value'>$value</option>"; } 
?>

</div>
</td>
</tr> 
</select>

</html>
```

Comment: By the _original value_ you mean "Problem Area" ?

Comment: No, I wish to reset the value of area_options if the PROBLEM AREA is changed again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can achieve this using JQuery :

First, JQuery is a JavaScript library and it's purpose is to make it much easier to use JavaScript on your website. [Get started with jQuery](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_intro.asp)

So, to make this work, first you have to **Add jQuery to Your Web Page** by placing this `<script>` tag inside the `<head>` section.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Then, before the closing `</body>`, add this function :

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('select[name=area]').on('change', function() {
          $('select[name=area_options]').prop('selectedIndex',0);
        });
    });
</script>
```

The above code will *attach a function to handle the change event to the `<select>` ("area")*.

Comment: Please, who ever down-voted this answer, kindly provide the reason !

Comment: I have tried placing this code inside the <head></head> and before </body>. It doesn't seem to be functioning.

Comment: Your JQuery script worked correctly once I set it beneath my Javascript call to my .js file  <script type='text/javascript' src=scripts.js'></script>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>